# Android support for viewport meta tag properties?

Tags: android, meta-tags, viewport

For quick-and-dirty mobile dev, we often propose that html5 apps designed primarily for a handheld that now want to support a tablet experience zoom the viewport in a bit for tablets.

The UX argument is that the app has a simplified streamlined interface already for the handheld, so there isn't a big need to re-arrange pages wholesale for the tablet.

For iOS, we add this to handle it:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width*.75, initial-scale=1.5, minimum-scale=1.5, maximum-scale=1.5, user-scalable=no">
```

So, same code base, but on the iPad the interface appears zoomed in 150%.

Should that same logic work fine on Android devices?

We're very early in prototyping so will eventually be testing this directly, but at the moment I have no access to actual android tablets. However, we're getting some second hand reports that people aren't seeing the zoomed in interface on their android tablet.